# Fix the palindrome output code

Tags: javascript

I need help with the way my palindrome code gives the results so that it will display the word and not show whatever word you put in backwards if its a palindrome or not.

```
function palinDrome() {
    var textval = document.getElementById("somTxt").value;
    var resulttxt = "";
    for (i = textval.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        resulttxt += textval.charAt(i);

    }
    if (textval === resulttxt) {

        document.getElementById("result8").innerHTML = resulttxt + " is a palindrome";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("result8").innerHTML = resulttxt + " is not a palindrome";
    }

}
```

Comment: soooo. where do you struggle? Cannot read a clear question

Comment: Change `restulttxt` to `textval`: `document.getElementById("result8").innerHTML = resulttxt + " is a palindrome";`

Comment: Say if you were to put in the word testing since its not a palindrome it will give you the result gnitset is not a palindrome and I'm trying to  have it just say testing is not a palindrome.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: You can shorten your code by using array methods and ternary operator: https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/gqhpLjmo/

Answer (score 0):

Change `resulttxt` to `textval` inside your `if` block, that way you will display your original word.

```js
function palinDrome() {
    var textval = document.getElementById("somTxt").value;
    var resulttxt = "";
    for (i = textval.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        resulttxt += textval.charAt(i);
    }
    if (textval === resulttxt) {
        document.getElementById("result8").innerHTML = textval + " is a palindrome";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("result8").innerHTML = textval + " is not a palindrome";
    }
}

document.getElementById('checkPalindrom').addEventListener('click', palinDrome);
```

```html
<div id='result8'></div>
<input id='somTxt' type='text' value='testing'>
<button id='checkPalindrom'>Click</button>
```